# I would like to chain multiple mapreduce jobs in google app engine in Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, mapreduce

Caveat: I am new to Google App Engine and Python, but I have managed to implement a PageRank algorithm in Google App Engine so far.

Next, I would like to chain together three mapreduce jobs in Google App Engine. However, I do not understand how to pass the key-value pairs from the first mapreduce job to the second mapreduce job (and subsequently the second mapreduce job to the third) using BlobKeys. I attempted to follow that introduced on the following website:

http://mattfaus.com/2013/10/google-appengine-mapreduce-in-depth/

Which uses a BlobKeys class to pass the BlobKey from one mapreduce job to the next. I believe that I am implementing the python Class incorrectly, as when called, the "third_party" object is not recognized in the code below.

Might someone be able to point out where I am going wrong. Apologies for the inability to provide a locally-driven test. This seems to be a little bit of a beast!

Here is the class that I am attempting to use:

```
class BlobKeys(mapreduce.base_handler.PipelineBase):
  """Returns a dictionary with the supplied keyword arguments."""

  def run(self, keys):
    # Remove the key from a string in this format:
    # /blobstore/<key>
    return {
        "blob_keys": [k.split("/")[-1] for k in keys]
    }
```

And here is the Pipeline code that calls the class above (does not recognize the third_party object):

```
num_shards=2
# First define the parent pipeline job
class RecommenderPipeline(base_handler.PipelineBase):
  """A pipeline to run Recommender demo.

  Args:
    blobkey: blobkey to process as string. Should be a zip archive with
      text files inside.
  """

  def run(self, filekey, blobkey, itr):
    #logging.debug("filename is %s" % filekey)
    output1 = yield mapreduce_pipeline.MapreducePipeline(
        "recommender",
        "main.recommender_group_by_user_rating_map1",
        "main.recommender_count_ratings_user_freq_reduce1",
        "mapreduce.input_readers.BlobstoreLineInputReader",
        "mapreduce.output_writers.BlobstoreOutputWriter",
        mapper_params={
            "blob_keys": blobkey,
        },
        reducer_params={
            "mime_type": "text/plain",
        },
        shards=num_shards)


    # Code below takes output1 and feeds into second mapreduce job.
    # Pipeline library ensures that the second pipeline depends on first and 
    # does not launch until the first has resolved.
    output2 = (
    yield mapreduce_pipeline.MapreducePipeline(
        "recommender",
        "main.recommender_pairwise_items_map2",
        "main.recommender_calc_similarity_reduce2",
        "mapreduce.input_readers.BlobstoreLineInputReader",
        "mapreduce.output_writers.BlobstoreOutputWriter",
        mapper_params=( BlobKeys(output1)), #see BlobKeys Class!`
        # "blob_keys": [k.split("/")[-1] for k in keys]
        #"blob_keys": blobkey, # did not work since "generator pipelines cannot
        # directly access ouputs of the child Pipelines that it yields", this code
        # would require the generator pipeline to create a temporary dict object 
        # with the output of the first job - this is not allowed.
        # In addition, the string returned by BobStoreOutputWriter is in the format
        # /blobstore/<key>, but BlobStoreLineInputReader expects only "<key>"
        # To solve these problems, use the BlobKeys class above.
        #},
        #mapper_params={
        #    #"blob_keys": [k.split("/")[-1] for k in output1]
        #    "blob_keys": blobkey.split("/")[-1],
        #},
        reducer_params={
            "mime_type": "text/plain",
        },
        shards=num_shards))

    # Code below takes output2 and feeds into third mapreduce job.
    # Pipeline library ensures that the third pipeline depends on second and 
    # does not launch until the second has resolved.
    output3 = (
    yield mapreduce_pipeline.MapreducePipeline(
        "recommender",
        "main.recommender_calculate_ranking_map3",
        "main.recommender_ranked_items_reduce3",
        "mapreduce.input_readers.BlobstoreLineInputReader",
        "mapreduce.output_writers.BlobstoreOutputWriter",
        mapper_params=( BlobKeys(output2)), #see BobKeys Class!`
        #mapper_params={
        #    "blob_keys": blobkey.split("/")[-1],
        #},
        reducer_params={
            "mime_type": "text/plain",
        },
        shards=num_shards))
    yield StoreOutput("Recommender", filekey, output3, itr)  #stores key to results so you can look at it.
```

I am wondering if I am having more of an issue using a Python Class properly, or more of an issue implementing this in GAE. I suspect a mixture of the two. Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A pipeline argument can be a concrete value or a PipelineFutures (and in that case it will wait until the future's value is available).
In your case you are passing a PipelineFutures as a parameter to a concrete value (BlobKeys).
Instead try yielding BlobKeys(output1) and passing its result as a parameter to the next pipeline.
e.g:
output1_1 = yield BlobKeys(output1)
output2 = yield mapreduce_pipeline.MapreducePipeline(..., mapper_params=output1_1,...)

Comment: Thanks for your reply ozarov! Your advice is now allowing me to pass the output from the first mapreduce job to the second (I have not turned on the third yet). However the data passed on to the second mapreduce job is one long string, of key-value, key-value pairs. Do you know if it is possible to pass on one key-value pair at a time. Or will I need to parse a string of key-value pairs as if starting a completely new MapReduce job?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. If BlobKeys returns a map with one key ("blob_keys") and a value which is a list of strings I would expect that mapper param to be kept as list (and not as one string of key value pairs). Are you experiencing something different?

Comment: The key consists of two values, which I now realize gets passed as a string. The values remain a list, but consist of strings (that look like tuples). I am having a hard time parsing out the values at the moment.   :(  see:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24182956/valueerror-could-not-convert-string-to-float-1/24183148?iemail=1&noredirect=1#24183148