# ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1'

Tags: python, python-2.7, floating-point

I am throughly confused as I confirmed that the variable I am trying to convert to a float is indeed a string (I will show my log here):

```
>>> print ratingXf
'1'
>>> print type(ratingXf)
<type 'str'>
>>> ratingX = float(ratingXf)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1'
```

And I calculate it as follows:

```
rateX, rateY= v.split(',')
ratingXf = (rateX[1:])
ratingX = float(ratingXf)
```

And when I try to convert the string to an integer, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: "'1'"
```

Seems this should be straightforward. But I do not understand why I am getting this error. Can anyone spot the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Try `print repr(ratingXf)`

Comment: v is ('1', '1')
but I use v.split(',') which gives ["('1'", " '1')"]

Comment: v is a tuple? Or is v = "'1', '1'"? Tuple doesn't have a split method…

Comment: No, v is not a tuple. it is a nested string, which posed problems. I had to remove spaces and do a few hacks to get it to work. Just wondering if there was a simpler way?!

Comment: See my updated answer. You can use the lambda to convert each rating string to a list of floats, making them much easier to access.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a nested string i.e. `ratingX = "'1'"`.

For your starting point of `values =  ["('1', '1')", "('1', '1')"]`

I suggest getting it into the format you want first:

```python
clean_cell = lambda x: map(float, re.findall(r'\'([0-9]+)\'', x))
values_cleaned = map(clean_cell, values)

# Then iterate
for rating in values_cleaned:
    if (len(rating) == 2):
        ratingX, ratingY = rating[0], rating[1] # This step is probably not necessary :P
        deal_with_ratings(ratingX, ratingY)
```

Comment: `int("'1'")` and `float("'1'")` produce the same errors the OP is getting, so it does seem like it, yes

Comment: I think that is the case.  I have been trying to strip the extra quotes. Is this the right approach or is there a more elegant way?

Comment: I am doing all of this in Google App Engine using MapReduce. It is being passed via BlobKeys. I have a string of values that looks like this:

    values = ["('1', '1')", "('1', '1')", "('5', '5')", "('1', '1')",
"('5', '5')", "('5', '5')"]

I loop through values as so:

    for v in values:

and the first v is:

    ('1', '1')

which is a string (not a tuple) when I check.

So when I do the following:

     (rateX, rateY)= v.split(',')
     ratingXf = (rateX[1:])
     ratingYf = (rateY[:-1])

I get strings for:

    ratingX =  '1'
   ratingYf =  '1'

Comment: However, repr(ratingXf) =  "'1'", indicating that rateXf is a nested
string. I have tried regex, strip(), and a few other ways to try and
extract the value so that I can turn it into a float (I get an error
every time I try float()), but do not succeed.

Comment: Ok, it all makes sense :)
Updated answer.